# Excel VBA Convert Cell Name to It's Coordinates

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I have this string which represents a cell: `A2`.
What should I do to covert it to coordinates: `(2, 1)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Without VBA**

Suppose, cell `C2` contains string `"A2"`.

Then

- `=INDIRECT(C2)` returns reference to `A2`
- `=ROW(INDIRECT(C2))` returns row number - `2`
- `=COLUMN(INDIRECT(C2))` returns column number - `1`
- `="(" & ROW(INDIRECT(C2)) & "; " & COLUMN(INDIRECT(C2)) & ")"` returns coordinates in format `(x; y)` - `(2; 1)`

[image]

**UPD:**

If you're using UDF, change your parameter type from `String` to `Range`:

```
Function GetData(Cell As Range)
    MsgBox "My row is " & Cell.Row
    MsgBox "My column is " & Cell.Column
End Function
```

if you call this UDF from worksheet like this: `=GetData(A2)`, msg box would pop-up:

- "My row is 2"
- "My column is 1"

Comment: `=offset(ref,rows,cols,width,height)` may also be of good use in the context.

Comment: @AnDrOiD, I noticed you're using function `Function GetData(Cell As String)...` Are you using it like user defined function (from worksheet in cell `=GetData(A2)`) and want to define coordinates of `A2`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Column and Row properties of the Range object:

```
Range("A2").Row
Range("A2").Column
```

Examlpe:

```
Sub test()
  Dim x As String
  x = "A2"
  MsgBox GetRow(x) & " " & GetColumn(x)
End Sub

 Function GetRow(Cell As String)
    GetRow = Range(Cell).Row
 End Function


 Function GetColumn(Cell As String)
    GetColumn = Range(Cell).Column
 End Function
```

Comment: Yeah I know that, but I meant what type of variable?

Comment: So why that doesn't work?
Function GetData(Cell As String)
    GetData = Range(Cell).Row
End Function

Comment: @AnDrOiD `=GetData("A2")` works (returns 2 when run from a spreadsheet cell).

Comment: Try the example i posted and see if that works for you.

Comment: @DimitrisKalaitzis Where do I write the `Sub` function?

Comment: Open Visual Basic Editor (Alt+F11), insert a new module and paste all the code there.

Comment: This should get the value from a specific cell from another sheet: http://i.imgur.com/GJU6Duf.png Why it doesn't work?

Comment: I would also like to add "As Integer" => Function GetRow(Cell As String) As Integer to define the return of the function as an integer instead as a Variant